# How do I generate keystrokes in a non-form application

Tags: c#, multithreading, automation, sendkeys

So I have a huge program and decided I should make one of the methods run in a separate thread. So I put the method in a separate class, an activated it on my form. It seemed to worked just how I wanted it to until it got to part where it gave me this error:

> SendKeys cannot run inside this application because the application
>   is not handling Windows messages.  Either change the application to
>   handle messages, or use the SendKeys.SendWait method.

I tried looking for the answer online. I think I saw something about how SendKeys only works in a Form or something.

Can anyone tell me a way to simulate a keystroke without using SendKeys, OR a way to get SendKeys to work in a different, non-form thread?

Comment: please show some source... what exactly have you tried ?

Comment: Just pretend it goes like this.

public class example()
{
    Sendkeys.Send("{RIGHT}");
}

but that doesn't work because of the error I get.

Comment: @user1219649 instead of us pretending, show us what you are currently doing and you will get a lot more useful answers

Comment: Fine. That class above is what I'm trying to run

Comment: The message is not very accurate.  It should read "SendKeys cannot run because the *thread* is not handling Windows messages."  Using SendKeys is almost always a Really Bad Idea.  Can't give you a good one without a reason you are doing this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your console application needs a message loop. This is done through the [Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6y6135ed.aspx) class. You will need to call [Application.Run(ApplicationContext)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157901.aspx).

```
class MyApplicationContext : ApplicationContext 
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args) 
    {
        // Create the MyApplicationContext, that derives from ApplicationContext,
        // that manages when the application should exit.
        MyApplicationContext context = new MyApplicationContext();

        // Run the application with the specific context. It will exit when
        // the task completes and calls Exit().
        Application.Run(context);
    }

    Task backgroundTask;

    // This is the constructor of the ApplicationContext, we do not want to 
    // block here.
    private MyApplicationContext() 
    {
        backgroundTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(BackgroundTask);
        backgroundTask.ContinueWith(TaskComplete);
    }

    // This will allow the Application.Run(context) in the main function to 
    // unblock.
    private void TaskComplete(Task src)
    {
        this.ExitThread();
    }

    //Perform your actual work here.
    private void BackgroundTask()
    {
        //Stuff
        SendKeys.Send("{RIGHT}");
        //More stuff here
    }
}
```

Comment: The code above gave me a few errors, actually. The "this.Exit()" doesn't work because it says Exit() doesn't exist. And also when I try to call the class from my main form, it gives me an error, saying "'class' is inaccessible due to its protection level". Any help?

Comment: This.Exit did not work because you likely forgot to make the class inherit from ApplicationContext. The accessability level is because it has a private constructor. However if you are using this code from a form it should be unnessasary. This is for getting a message loop in a console app. For a forms application just use a BackgroundWorker and put your sendkeys code there.

Answer (score 1):

I Know this not an answer, but this how i used to do using ActiveX and Script

```
Set ws = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

str = "Hi there... ~ Dont click your mouse while i am typing." & _
" ~~This is a send key example, using which you can send your keystrokes"
ws.Run("notepad.exe")
WScript.Sleep(1000)

For c=1 To Len(str)
WScript.Sleep(100) 'Increase the value for longer delay
ws.SendKeys Mid(str,c,1)
Next
```

Save this code as `file.vbs` and double click to execute in windows machine.