# Loop the whole consoleApp

Tags: c#, loops, math, console

Hey i have this math console application that i would like to loop.
Its written in Swedish, but the basic just is that after the "Console.ReadKey();" which acts as a pause the application should start over from the beginning. Much like you can do with .bat files using "start" and "goto: start".

So basically i would like to start the app all over again, it dosnt matter if its done by clearing the screen and then applying the code all over again or by closing and reopening the CMD window.

Great regards Oscar Andersson 17 Sweden, tech student.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Förberedelser
        Random numberGenerator = new Random();
        int num01 = numberGenerator.Next(1,11);
        int num02 = numberGenerator.Next(1,11);

        //Frågan
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
        Console.Write("Vad är ");
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        Console.Write(num01 + " ");
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
        Console.Write("gånger ");
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        Console.Write(num02);
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
        Console.WriteLine(" ?");

        //Svaret
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;
        int numKey = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine());
        if (numKey == num01 * num02)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            Console.WriteLine("\n Grattis du svarade rätt!");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.Write("\n Du svarade tyvärr fel. \n Svaret är ");
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            Console.WriteLine(num01 * num02);
        }

        //Avslut och loop
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: Simplest way is to wrap it all inside a `while(true)` statement. Of course, this isn't the cleanest way since you don't have a defined 'end' scenario.

Comment: Yeah was trying to avoid that, but if anyone else here doesnt have an idea i will have to give it a try.
:D ty anyways.

Comment: @Vlad okay thank you Vlad, ended up using While. Much more nice looking and than i thought. :D

Comment: create a boolean, wrap a while with the boolean around your application. Ask the user if he wants to go again, if not set bool to false and quit.

Comment: Even though its a console app, you could use NotifyIcon to get a sys tray icon that you can rightclick and select Exit. Selecting Exit will then set your bool in your while(mybool) to false.

Comment: Thank you @Max , I will try that in another app. :)

Comment: That sounds really cool @Wolf5 !!! :D

Comment: To exit the Console.ReadKey() you should try sending a keypress. Look at this topic for that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057608/how-do-i-generate-keystrokes-in-a-non-form-application . Or maybe there is another nifty way to exit a Console.ReadKey() that is waiting for a key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wrap a while around your application and ask the user if he/she wants to quit when at end of the loop:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    bool continueApplication = true;

    while(continueApplication) {
    //Förberedelser
    Random numberGenerator = new Random();
    int num01 = numberGenerator.Next(1,11);
    int num02 = numberGenerator.Next(1,11);

    //Frågan
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
    Console.Write("Vad är ");
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
    Console.Write(num01 + " ");
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
    Console.Write("gånger ");
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
    Console.Write(num02);
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
    Console.WriteLine(" ?");

    //Svaret
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;
    int numKey = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine());
    if (numKey == num01 * num02)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        Console.WriteLine("\n Grattis du svarade rätt!");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.Write("\n Du svarade tyvärr fel. \n Svaret är ");
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        Console.WriteLine(num01 * num02);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Do you want to continue(y/n)?");
    //Read what the user typed
    string result = Console.ReadLine();
    //Will allow N as well
    result = result.ToLower();
    //Check if the user typed n
    if(result == "n") {
        continueApplication = false;
    }
}
```